What's the benefit or drawback of being Small?
The D&D Free Rules (2024) just came out, and one surprising change is that humans can now be either Medium or Small size. Similarly, the Heavy weapon property has also changed, from imposing Disadvantage on Small creatures to imposing Disadvantage on creatures with below 13 Strength (for melee weapons) or Dexterity (for ranged ones). This poses an interesting change, as things like the Heavy property used to be some of the biggest impacts.
What are the benefits and drawbacks to being Small size, as opposed to Medium size?

Benefits of being Small instead of Medium

You can move through the space of non-allied Large creatures, as they are two sizes larger than you. You also block non-allied Tiny creatures from passing through your space. ("Combat" -> "Movement and Position" -> "Moving around Other Creatures")

You probably have an easier time acquiring Cover, as Cover is offered by something covering "at least half", "at least three-quarters" or "the whole" target, and a Small creature is usually shorter in height than a Medium one. ("Combat" -> "Cover")

You can ride Medium creatures, because they are larger than the rider. ("Combat" -> "Mounted Combat") This is a benefit because you do not take extra space when mounted, allowing you easier movement in dungeons.

Narrow openings sized for Small creatures are not Difficult Terrain for you. You can also enter narrow openings sized for Tiny creatures. (Glossary -> "Difficult Terrain")


Drawbacks of being Small instead of Medium

If you end a turn in the same space as a Small or Medium creature, you will fall prone because they are not smaller than you. ("Combat" -> "Movement and Position" -> "Moving around Other Creatures")

You cannot Grapple or Shove a Large creature, because grapples and shoves are only possible "if the target is no more than one size larger than you". (Glossary -> "Unarmed Strike")

Large creatures can drag you after grappling without being slowed down, because you are two sizes smaller. (Glossary -> "Grappled")

You probably have a lower reach when High Jumping. Because a Small creature is usually shorter in height than a Medium one, and

you can reach a distance equal to the height of the jump plus 1½ times your height.

(Glossary -> "High Jump")

Furniture sized for Small creatures is Difficult Terrain for you. (Glossary -> "Difficult Terrain")



Can they also squeeze through tiny gaps? They could in the old rules, I couldn't find anything for it in 2024.

@TreeSpawned neither did I, I think the difficult terrain section replaced that. The old rule said you could squeeze into an opening for a creature 1 size smaller, but it was difficult terrain, and you had other penalties.

You can also prevent enemy Tiny creatures from moving through your space, right?

+1 for mentioning difficult terrain. I did not know that. :)

Creature Size
The Creature Size of a medium or small creature is a 5'x5' square. Your size impacts:

During your move, you can pass through the space of an ally, a creature that has the Incapacitated condition (see the rules glossary), a Tiny creature, or a creature that is two sizes larger or smaller than you.
Another creature’s space is Difficult Terrain for you unless that creature is Tiny or your ally.
You can’t willingly end a move in a space occupied by another creature. If you somehow end a turn in a space with another creature, you have the Prone condition (see the rules glossary) unless you are Tiny or are of a larger size than the other creature.

So, just from size alone, you can bypass or be bypassed by a Large creature, or forced prone by any small or larger creature if you end in their space.
You do however block a Tiny creature, unlike a medium one.
Mounts

A willing creature that is at least one size larger than a rider and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount, using the following rules.

You can ride on a medium creature, and don't require a large creature.
Grappling/Grappled/Unarmed Strike
A Large or larger creature moves faster if it grapples you, as you impose no drawback on them.
You can't grapple such a creature, as they are more than one category larger, and neither can you shove them.
Terrain
Furniture of small or larger is difficult terrain for you.
An opening that fits only a Tiny creature is difficult terrain for you, but impossible for a medium creature.
Cracks/squeek through?
The Free rules do not mention squeaking through an opening that is smaller than you, such an opening seems to be just difficult terrrain and that's it. There is no category smaller than Tiny.
Body Height Dependency
Cover & High Jumping depend on your body height.
Equipment
Using the alternate rule, your equipment needs to be made for small creatures, or adapted for 1d4*10 percent of the item's price, unless they are magical
